Manifest merger failed with multiple errors when building an app but apks are generated just fine
I have encountered the above error after updating my Android Studio to Jelly Fish 2023.3.1. The error occurs when I clean and rebuild the project:
D:\Directory\ProjName\navcomponent\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest8595131114998106621.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity.
    Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
    See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

D:\Directory\ProjName\navcomponent\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest8595131114998106621.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity.
    Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
    See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

D:\Directory\ProjName\navcomponent\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest8595131114998106621.xml:41:9-47:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity.
    Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
    See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

My project doesn't have classes like BootsStrapActivity, EmptyAcitivity or EmptyFloatingActivity.
NavComponent is the library that has been added as module in my project and its manifest file is as follows:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.ibrahimsn.lib" >

</manifest>

I have added the exported attribute to every component tag i.e. activity, receiver, service, provider.
When I look at the merged manifest file it only shows warnings and no Manifest Merging Error.
Invalidate cache and restart, cache manually deleted doesn't work as well. I have also updated the following dependencies because some questions suggested to update them.
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

My app is running and apk build is generated successfully but I want to remove this error, it shouldn't show up on every clean and build.

Please replace the screenshot with the error message pasted as text so we can easily copy&paste it. Also, redacting your local directory structure will be more effective.

@Leviathan I have edited it. Please have a look. Thanks.

When you open your manifest file there should be a "Text" and a "Merged Manifest" tab at the bottom. Do you find any of the problemtic activities (like EmptyActivity) in the "Merged Manifest" tab? Does it have the exported attribute?

Also, can you still execute your instrumentation tests?

I can't see any thing related that activities in merged Manifest tab. I can generate the sdk and run the application successfully still.

Since the problem seems to be related to the instrumentation tests it won't affect the app itself (which is why you can still run it and build an apk). That's why I asked if your instrumentation tests are still working. Also please verify the unit tests although I would guess that they shouldn't be affected.

instrumentation test is working fine of my app as well as the module I have added it the navComponent but still getting the navcomponent:processDebugAndroidTestManifest error. Though my app unit test is working fine too.
